# Is there a way to embed sequence diagrams in rustdoc?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

As they say, one picture is worth 1000 words. I'd like to embed several `sequence diagrams` in my generated `rust documentation`. Is there a way to do this? Having an `embedded image` doesn't really work, it is harder to maintain, it is an asset outside of the docs, etc.

Comment: That is exactly why I dislike Markdown/CommonMark as a documentation format - lack of extensibility.

Answer (score 3):

The most universal method would just be a text-based diagram in a non-code code block.

````
/// This module contains structs and functions for communicating to and from
/// the server. It is very important that you understand this diagram so you
/// will appreciate how much work has gone into this. Just look at it! Its
/// beautiful!
/// 
/// ```none
/// +------------+          +------------+
/// |   Client   |          |   Server   |
/// +------------+          +------------+
///       |                        |
///       | request("/")           |
///       +----------------------> |
///       |                        |
///       |             response() |
///       | <----------------------+
///       |                        |
///       |                        |
///       v                        v
/// ```
/// 
/// Appreciating the diagram will give you a +1 to confidence for the rest of
/// the day.
pub mod connection {

}
````

Will end up rendering like this:

[image: generated docs]

Its up to you whether this acceptable and/or practical.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at:
https://docs.rs/crate/mdbook-plantuml/0.3.0

Plantuml is a really good tool to describe sequence diagram using easy to maintain text.
Here is a sample from [plantuml website](https://plantuml.com/en/sequence-diagram):

[image]